# Determine the value for which a sequence is an arithmetic progression.

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have the following sequence $$ -a, -\dfrac{a}{b}, \dfrac{a}{b}, a$$

Determine the value of $b$ for which this is an arithmetic progression ($a \neq 0$)

I don't know how to do this. I've tried adding a variable and making a couple of equations:

- $-a + x = -\dfrac{a}{b}$
- $ -a + 2x = \dfrac{a}{b}$
- $-a + 3x = a$

But this doesn't seem to yield any logical answers. Just from looking at the sequence it seems that $b=2$ should be the answer, but I can't seem to get that result..

Comment: We write $1-\frac{1}{b} = \frac{2}{b}$. So, $b=3$. We still know nothing about a.

Comment: Your method is absolutely right. All you had to do is obtain the value of $x$ from the first equation and put it in the second equation to get a relation between $a$ & $b$. You would have right away got the value of $b$ by dividing the equation by $a$. This is an acceptable method as we don't care about $a$ and it is already declared that it is non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an arithmetic progression, $a - \frac{a}{b} = \frac{a}{b} - \frac{-a}{b}$, i.e. $t_{i+1} - t_{i}$ is constant $\forall\; i$.

Note that $a\cdot(1-\frac{1}{b})=a\cdot(\frac{1}{b} - \frac{-1}{b})$. We write $1-\frac{1}{b} = \frac{2}{b}$. So, $b=3$. We still know nothing about a.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Note that $a\cdot(1-\frac{1}{b})=a\cdot(\frac{1}{b} - \frac{-1}{b})$.

Comment: Can you in your answer explain why this must be the case?

Comment: Note that an obvious exception is $a=0$. In this case, $\frac{1}{b}$ only need be well-defined.

Comment: See answer for additional details.

Comment: Thanks, that's clear. Upvoted. But can you explain why my method is incorrect (in that it yields incorrect answers)?

Comment: Suppose $b=2$. Then, $-a+x=\frac{-a}{2}$, which implies $x = \frac{a}{2}$. However, $-a+2\cdot \frac{a}{2} = 0$. So, $b=2$ fails to satisfy the first two equations...

Comment: Thanks, I now realize that my method also yield $b=3$. Thanks for the tremendous help.

Answer (score 0):

As a high-school student, I am taught that inorder to easily solve things in any system, you first need to find the exploitable properties of the system that will help you attain your solution.

Here, we can use the following fact of arithmetic progressions to our advantage:

> The sum of the extremes is twice the mean.
>
> ie, The double of any term is equal to the sum of any two terms equally distant from it.

Let us first assume that `-a, -a/b, a/b, a` does form an A.P.

According to what we know about the first 3 terms,
$$ 2 * (\frac{-a}{b}) = -a + \frac{a}{b}$$
$$\implies a = \frac{2a}{b} + \frac{a}{b}$$
$$\implies b = \frac{3a}{a}$$
$$\implies b = 3$$

So, as you can see, it does not matter what the value of $a$ is as long as it is not zero.
You can verify this answer by doing the same with the last 3 terms. It may be interesting to note that the common difference of this progression is $\frac{2a}{3}$

It is an important and popular fact that things are not always what they seem.
At first glance, you mistook the value of $b$ to be 2 as you thought you saw the following sequence:
`-1, -1/2, 0, 1/2, 1`
But notice the zero in the middle of this sequence.
It's a very easy mistake to make but in future, analyze the question a bit more before jumping to conclusions :D